# Corollary Of Jordan Decomposition Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $\mu$ is a signed measure on $(X,\mathbf{A}$), prove for all $A \in \mathbf{A}$ that

$$\mu^+(A)=\sup\{\mu(B): B \in \mathbf{A}, B \subset A\}$$

and

$$\mu^-(A)=-\inf \{\mu(B): B \in \mathbf{A}, B \subset A\}.$$

So I know we can decomposte $X$ into $P \cup N$ with $P \cap N = \emptyset$ where $P$ is a positive set and $N$ is a negative set. Then I define

$$\mu^+(A)=\mu(A \cap P)$$

and

$$\mu^-(A)=-\mu(A \cap N).$$

And I know this simplfies to showing

$$\mu(A \cap P)=\sup\{\mu(B): B \in \mathbf{A}, B \subset A\}$$
and
$$\mu(A \cap N)=\inf \{\mu(B): B \in \mathbf{A}, B \subset A\}.$$

And I know As $A \cap P \subset P$ we have $\mu(A \cap P) \geq 0$ and as $A \cap N \subset N$, $\mu(A \cap N) \leq 0$. Also $B \subset A$ means $B \subset A \cap N$ and same for $P$. I've been stuck on this for a while. Any help or tips or hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some $A \in \textbf{A}$, and any $B \subseteq A$. Then

$$\mu(B) = \mu^{+}(B) - \mu^{-}(B) \leq \mu^{+}(B) \leq \mu^{+}(A) = \mu(A \cap P) $$

This holds for all $B \subseteq A$ so you can take a supremum to get

$$ \sup \left( \mu(B) : B \subseteq A \right) \leq \mu(A \cap P)$$

The other side of this inequality should be easy enough, and the proof for $\mu^{-}$ should be analogous.

Comment: Wow I didn’t realize it was that easy.. and the decomposition into $\mu^+-\mu^-$ is guaranteed to us by the Jordan decomposition theorem, correct?

Comment: Yeah that's right! I remember getting confused over this one myself when first seeing it. The key I think is to remember that despite the notation, the way define we define $\mu^{-}$  gives $\mu^{-} \geq 0$ so that first inequality comes easy.

Comment: Cool thanks! Also, I appreciate you paying it forwards as you’ve struggled w this as well! I also answer tons of questions on here and Quora to give back :)